# Color replacement in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors

I have an image whose background I want to convert from silver to black. The color replacement doesn't work. It did work for replacing the foreground color but nothing happens on using color replacement tool on the silver color.

My image is: [image]

The target color when using color replacement tool is #424243 (a dark black shade). Pls let me know what are my options to get this working.

Comment: You're better off recreating this image. Just pen tool the outline, and fill it with black.

Comment: I actually used your suggestion and it worked. Had to do some adjustments with brush tool though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The <kbd>Edit > Replace Color</kbd> tool might work for you:

[image: Photoshop replace color example]

Fiddle with the Fuzziness and Lightness settings to suit your needs. More information on various color replacement techniques within Photoshop are available in [Adobe's help docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/matching-replacing-mixing-colors.html).

Comment: Huh.. I guess I haven't opened Photoshop in a while. Nice work.

Comment: cool, but I already went ahead with @MichaelFrank's suggestion. Your solution looks good and Michael's also worked well for me :)